# CDbCommand Error: General Error 26 file is encrypted or not a database

Tags: php, mysql, database, yii

So I have this error, and I am not sure how to fix it. I have a cache.x.x.xx.db file under the runtime folder that I have deleted based on another error I was having, but then I got error 13 database full or does not exist. So I replaced the .db file and now it is giving me error 26 file is encrypted or not a database. Any ideas? I believe it has something to do with Yii Framework but I can't seem to find the problem. Thanks!

Comment: What did you replace it with?

Comment: I literally replaced it with a copy of the same file, which is what threw me off. I originally deleted it because I was getting error 1 table yii cache already exists. So I deleted it, got error 13 database is full, replaced it and got error 26.

But I found a fix I believe. I replaced it with a backup from the day before and it worked. I also pointed yii to the main db and set autoCreateTable to false in CDbHttpSession and everything seems to be working fine since yesterday.

Any idea what would cause this? Thanks for your response!